# Create a public function/sub to set CSS and other properties

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to create a Public Sub / Function that will allow me to pass certain variables into it and this will affect the output. e.g.

DIV ID = InfoDiv
CSS Class = "Warning"
LBInfoMsg.Text = "An Error has occured"
DIV Visibility = True or False

I would like to type something similar in the code behind page:

```
InfoMsg(InfoDiv, "warning", "An Error has Occured", True)
```

**I know this is wrong but here is what I have tried so far and failed...**

```
Public Sub InfMsg(ByRef MyDIV As System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl, ByRef CSS As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Style, ByVal strMessage As String)
        strMessage = strMessage.Replace("'", "''")
        MyDIV.Attributes.Add("Style", "warning")
        MyDIV.Visible = "True"

    End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you passing `MyDiv` & `CSS` both as `ByRef`? Do you intend to change the reference within your `InfMsg` call?

Comment: They are only in there as I was experimenting with it as its something I am not familiar with. I want to change the reference whenever possible so I can use it multiple times in the same page if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without getting too advanced into Lambdas and such, here's what I came up with based on the detail you gave:

```
Public Sub InfMsg(ByRef MyDIV As System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl, ByRef CssClass As String, ByVal strMessage As String, ByVal visible As Boolean)

    MyDIV.Attributes("style") = "visibility:" & If(visible, "visible", "hidden") & ";"
    Dim lbl As New Label
    lbl.CssClass = CssClass
    lbl.Text = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(strMessage)
    MyDIV.Controls.Add(lbl)

End Sub
```

Comment: Is your example based on VB or C#? Thanks

Comment: Almost there! Instead of the Label attributes receiving the CssClass, I need the DIV to get the CssClass. I tried the following but it doesnt seem to work!  

        MyDIV.Attributes("style") = "visibility:" & If(visible, "visible", "hidden") & CssClass & ";"
        Dim lblInform As New Label
        MyDIV.Attributes("style") = CssClass
        lblInform.Text = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(strMessage)
        MyDIV.Controls.Add(lblInform)

Comment: I'm assuming CssClass is a .class defined in a .css file for your site. to assign a class to an element, you do something like "<a class="Class" />. That is, the class gets assigned to the class attribute. Therefore, you need to change your code to MyDIV.Attributes("class") = CssClass